# Initialize struct with byte array based on header type

Tags: c#, struct, arrays

I have several structs in my file. I want to pass a byte array and initialize the the struct. I have tried struct to byte array conversion and vice versa but I am getting errors like "Attempted to read or write protected memory". So I thought passing byte array to initialize the struct might be more efficient. My problem is that one part of structure is dependent of first byte type. So how do I assign another structure to it?

Here is the code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public struct Payload
{
    MessageTypeID ID1;   
    MessageTypeID ID2;  
    Byte[] PayloadData; 

    public Payload(byte[] payloadArray)
    {
        this.ID1 = (MessageTypeID) payloadArray[0];
        this.ID2 = (MessageTypeID) payloadArray[1];

        switch (this.ID1)
        {
            case MessageTypeID.TEMPERATURE:
                byte[] tempPayloadArray = new byte[payloadArray.Length - 2];
                Temperature temp = new Temperature(Array.Copy(payloadArray,2,tempPayloadArray,0,payloadArray.Length - 2);
                this.PayloadData = temp;  <== ERROR: Cannot convert Temperature to byte[]
                break;
            case MessageTypeID.LEVEL:
            .......
        }
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct Temperature
{
    Byte LocalTemp;         
    Int16 ExternalTemp1;                                  
    Int16 ExternalTemp2;   

    public Temperature(byte[] tempArray)
    {
        this.LocalTemp = tempArray[0];
        this.ExternalTemp1 = tempArray[1];
        this.ExternalTemp2 = tempArray[2];
    }
}
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct Level
{
    Byte FluidLevel;        
    Int16 FreshnessTimer;   
    Byte CalibrationChannelReading; 

    public Level(byte[] levelArray)
    {
        this.FluidLevel = levelArray[0];
        this.FreshnessTimer = BitConverter.ToInt16(levelArray, 1);
        this.CalibrationChannelReading = levelArray[3];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Why do you want to assign temp to PayLoadData? If your requirement is that you need a new byte array that needs to be assigned to PayLoadData which represents the structure data then have the Tempearate and other structure return byte array that it represents. (You can keep this in base class if all structs do that)

Comment: I want to structure the array such that if the payload is of type e.g. temperature, then bytes are organized in the right fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't roll your own: Use the infrastructure .Net and the CLR provides for you.

If you need to interoperate with unmanaged code, you need to learn about P/Invoke and marshalling:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66245/Marshaling-with-C-Chapter-Introducing-Marshaling
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd10k43k(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsvc/archive/2009/02/18/marshalling-complicated-structures-using-pinvoke.aspx

If you are interoperating with other managed code, you need to read about [`serialization`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx). More at

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675(v=vs.110).aspx

You can use stock binary serialization, or roll you own. In either case, you want your object to be [`ISerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which requires just one method be implemented for serializing your object into a bytestream: `void GetObjectData( SerializationInfo info , StreamingContext context )`.

And [implies] a corresponding constructor for deserializing the bytestream back into an object instance having the signature `constructor( SerializationInfo information, StreamingContext context)`.

For example:

```
[Serializable]
public class Widget : ISerializable
{
  public Widget( SerializationInfo serializationInfo , StreamingContext context )
  {
    // your rehydration logic here
  }
  public void GetObjectData( SerializationInfo info , StreamingContext context )
  {
    // your dehydration logic here
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I accpeted this as answer because although I didn't exactly do what you suggested I did use Serializable and OptionalField in my struct to make it work the way I wanted. Thank you!